How to disable a JS link when I click a real link?
I have a container with a JS link and inside two real links
<article class="jq-click-blank" data-href="https://www.google.com">
  Text text text 
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">real link 1</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">real link 2</a>
  Text text text 
</article>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('.jq-click').on( "click", function() {
        var jqlink = $(this).data('href');
        window.location.href = jqlink;
    });
      
    $('.jq-click-blank').on( "click", function() {      
        var jqlink = $(this).data('href');
        window.open(jqlink, '_blank');      
    });
    
});

</script>

If the user clicks anywhere inside the container it will be activate the JS link but if the user clicks one of the real link it should activate only the real link but right know it triggers both
I actually could make all of them JS link but this may cause SEO and usability issue
How can I prevent my JS ( jQuery ) link to be triggered if I click a real link inside the box?

The duplicate has your answer - use stopPropagation() on the child event - but that being said, having nested clickable elements is very rarely a good idea. The better solution would be to avoid the problem in this case.
